# grep username with perl script in OSX

Tags: perl

How to get currently active user name with perl script on Mac OSX
I use 'whoami' but is came with \n

```
my $username = `whoami`;
```

please suggest.

thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`getlogin`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getlogin.html) to get the login:

```
$username = getlogin || getpwuid($<);
```

Else, use [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) as [**ikegami**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) has suggested in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670912/grep-username-with-perl-script-in-osx/7671033#7671033).

Answer (score 5):

```
chomp( my $username = `whoami` );
```

[`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative for chomp might be to use regular expressions:

```
my $username = `whoami`
$username =~ s/\n//
```

Edit:

The previous regex only removes the first new line that it finds in the string, to remove only the last one you can use:

```
$username =~ s/\n$//;
```

To remove all the new lines at the end and the beginning you use:

```
$username =~ s/^\n+//;
$username =~ s/\n+$//;
```

Comment: That would remove the first newline, not the last as chomp does.  `whoami` *should* only return one line, but why risk it?